# How to find the chemical reaction velocity?

Tags: systems-of-equations, chemistry

Let me know if this problem should go to Chemistry SE.

So I've got a substrate complexing reaction that can be reversed before forming the product: $$2S + E \overset{k_+}{\longrightarrow} C \overset{k_{++}}{\longrightarrow} 2P + E, \quad C \overset{k_-}{\longrightarrow} 2S + E;$$

I'm a bit confused about the reaction rate coefficient given multiple same item reacted at the same time, so

1. Is $\dfrac{dC}{dt} = 2k_+ES - (k_- + k_{++})C$ or $k_+ES^2 - (k_- + k_{++})C$?
2. Is $\dfrac{dP}{dt} = k_{++}C/2$ or $k_{++}C$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can sort of only tell you that this is not a math question by knowing something about the modeling: in real life, actual ternary reactions where three objects have to encounter one another at the same time almost always proceed at a negligible rate compared to other reactions. Thus $2S+E \to C$ as a single step is practically guaranteed to be negligibly slow compared to something else.

Comment: So you would suggest me asking this in Chemistry SE?

Comment: That said, as for your second question, your reference might use different notation but I would assume the $k_{++}$ is referring to the contribution to $dC/dt$ from the dissociation being $-k_{++} C$, and in this case $dP/dt=2k_{++}C$. Regardless of how you notate things, your equations need to respect the balanced reactions (so the contribution to $dP/dt$ from the dissociation reaction must be $-2$ times the contribution to $dC/dt$ from that reaction).

Comment: The first issue should be resolved on Chemistry SE, and will probably need you to specify more about the underlying chemical context (for example, whether it is plausible that the "enzyme" can bind one substrate and then sit in that state for a while as it waits for another substrate to arrive, allowing your first reaction to proceed in two steps).

Comment: @Ian I thought we got $2P + E$ from each complex $C$ so $d(2P)/dt = 2 dP/dt = k_{++}C$ but thanks.

Comment: No, that's definitely wrong. Strip out the notation and think about the physics: each time you run the dissociation reaction, you lose a C and gain two P's. So the size of the change in the amount of P you have is twice as large as the size of the change in the amount of C you have (per time that the dissociation reaction is run, with nothing else happening).

Comment: @Ian So in case $k_-$ and $k_{++} = 0$, is $dC/dt = -2 \times dE/dt$ like you just said about $dP/dt$ and $dC/dt$? I didn't have the info about the reaction order of either $S$ or $E$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123886/discussion-between-yuki-f-and-ian).